# Unable to get name against the id in yii2 gridview

Tags: php, exception, gridview, yii2

I have a `index` view in which I have a field name `sub-division`. The field displays the id. But I want to display it's `name` instead of `ID`.

**What I have done?**

I have placed a function in my `Model`

```
 public function getSubdivision()
{
    return $this->hasOne(SurveyHescoSubdivision::className(), ['id' => 'sub_division']);
}
```

In my search model I have done filtering like

```
 $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'meter_id' => $this->meter_id,
        'created_by' => $this->created_by,
        'updated_by' => $this->updated_by,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        'store_id' => $this->store_id,
        'sub_division'=> $this->sub_division,
        'status'=>'Inventory Stored',

    ]);
```

And in my index view

```
[
            'label' => 'Sub-Division',
            'value' => function ($d) {
                    return $d->subdivision->name;
            },
            // 'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'sub_division', \common\models\SurveyHescoSubdivision::toArrayList(), ['prompt' => "Sub-Div", 'class' => 'form-control']),

        ],
```

The `table` has the `name` column against the `id`.

When I goto my index page I am getting the below exception

> Trying to get property of non-object

I have done this thing in other views but I don't know why this is showing

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subdivision id is empty, Use :

```
[
    'label' => 'Sub-Division',
    'value' => 'subdivision.name',
],
```

**OR**

```
[
    'label' => 'Sub-Division',
    'value' => function ($d) {
         return !empty($d->sub_division) ? $d->subdivision->name : null;
    },
],
```